# How Can I play local video from gallery in Avplayer ios obj c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is my code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
{
    UIImage *img=info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    self.imgOuter.image=img;

      [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSString *strMediaurl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSString *strMediaurlrefrenceurl =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];


    NSString *strtest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strMediaurl];

    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strtest];
    //filePath may be from the Bundle or from the Saved file Directory, it is just the path for the video
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
    AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
    playerViewController.player = player;
    [playerViewController.player play];
//       [player play];
    [self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: could you please provide what you are getting in 'videoURL'

Comment: file:/Users/saturncube/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A5329B99-8769-4FC8-AFD6-227F3B59188C/data/Containers/Data/Application/E79F1E7A-66BA-4F03-B9A4-9E7A9F0A62A2/tmp/trim.F5845EED-7EBC-4435-8832-04F7FD38478F.MOV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code. You are changing the url provided by Photolibrary that's why your file failed to play.

```
NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
```

Photolibrary itself providing valid url so directly use for playing

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
{
    UIImage *img = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    self.imgOuter.image=img;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
    AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
    playerViewController.player = player;
    [playerViewController.player play];
    [self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```